# How to get a new immutable object after modification?

Tags: android, kotlin, immutability

Suppose you have a huge nested object and then you want to modify one of its properties.

```
myData.x.y.z = 7;
// or...
myData.a.b.add(9);
```

It doesn't look like much of a problem, but the actual coding is not that simple.

```
data class Employee(
  val name: String
)

data class Company(
  val employees: List<Employee>
)

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

  // Expose screen UI state
  private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(Company(emptyList()))
  val uiState: StateFlow<Company> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

  // Handle business logic
  fun addEmployee(employee: Employee) {
    _uiState.update { currentState ->
      currentState.copy(
        employees = buildList {
          addAll(currentState.employees)
          add(employee)
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

In real code, based on the [Single source of truth](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture#single-source-of-truth) and [Unidirectional Data Flow](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture#unidirectional-data-flow) principles, it is necessary to use immutable data, which is implemented in Kotlin by the `val` keyword.

The nesting level of this object is not particularly deep, and the implemented function is `add`. If you want to update an element in `List`, the code will be more complicated, and `copy` a deeply nested object will also cause performance problems.

What is a method `doSomeThing` like the following to get a new immutable object after modification? It creates a copy of the object, modifies the properties of the new object as needed, and returns this new object.

```
fun addEmployee(employee: Employee) {
  _uiState.update { currentState ->
    doSomeThing {
      currentState.employees.add(employee)
    }
  }
}
```

Some examples are added below.

Change the `addEmployee()` function to `updateEmployee()` function.

```
fun updateEmployee(employee: Employee) {
  _uiState.update { currentState ->
    currentState.copy(
      employees = buildList {
        val index = currentState.employees.indexOfFirst { it.name == employee.name }
        val temp = currentState.employees.toMutableList()
        temp[index] = Employee("jack")
        temp.toList()
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Nested object

```
data class A(
  val b: B
)

data class B(
  val c: C
)

data class C(
  val d: D
)

data class D(
  val name: String
)

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
  fun updateEmployee(employee: Employee) {
    _uiState.update { currentState ->
      currentState.copy(
        b = currentState.b.copy(
          c = currentState.b.c.copy(
            d = currentState.b.c.d.copy(
              name = "John"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
buildList {
    addAll(currentState.employees)
    add(employee)
}
```

Kotlin already can do this without explicit mutation:

```
currentState.employees + employee
```

Also, Kotlin has

- separation between `List` and `MutableList`, `Set` and `MutableSet` and other collections
- bulk operations like `map`, `flatMap`, `reduce`, `fold`, `drop`, `take` [and more](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/#functions)
- Sequences which can do several bulk operations without creating a lot of copies

---

> copy a deeply nested object will also cause performance problems

Not much. When you're patching one field, other fields' values of a copy are still pointing to the same objects.

Comment: I added two new examples, can you tell how to write more concise code? For the former, I thought I could implement it with the `map()` function, but it doesn't feel elegant enough.

Comment: @FreedomFoolt, for replacing an element, you can check out [this (not very elegant) option](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/best-way-to-replace-an-element-of-an-immutable-list/8646/8)

Comment: I checked the link and this is no different to using the `map()` method. And how is the `nested object` example optimized?

Comment: @FreedomFoolt no need to optimize anything until you have a performance problem.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good, I am not referring to performance optimization, but to simplify the code, this coding is very similar to `callback hell`, isn't it?

Comment: @FreedomFoolt, well, sort of. I don't have an idea how to get rid of it.